# Reviewing posts question about argumentative posts

Tags: discussion

I went to review [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/31348).  The first sentence looked good (if short) but the second sounded pretty negative.  When I went to down vote it, there were no categories that discussed the tone of the post.  So, I was wondering if I should be checking for that.  I decided to not down voting it until I heard from some of the more experienced people here.

Personally, I can get a bit snarky but I try to edit that out of my posts unless I know the person I'm talking to.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't have categories.  Just click the down-arrow and that's it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "vote for deletion."  I'm learning the terminology of the board.

Comment: See [the help page](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).  «When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an **egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post**, or an **answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect**.»

Comment: @JDługosz, thank you.

Comment: I thing that’s *vote to **close**.*  You can [edit], you know.

Comment: @JDługosz, In this case the answer was two sentences.  The first one had a point, the second was just negativity.  There wouldn't have been much there unless I completely rewrote his answer for him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The linked answer has a few problems:

- It consists of exactly two sentences.
- Neither sentence actually addresses the question.
- The answer is rather passive-aggressive.

The first and third of those are discouraged on the site; feel free to downvote due to "[t]his answer is not useful." The second of those deserves the low-quality flag that put it in the review queue in the first place; feel free to vote to delete the answer or add a comment explaining the problems and why the post might be deleted.

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like it is gone already.  Does the poster get an explanation when their post is deleted or is it just gone?  It would be nice if this could be a teaching point.

Comment: @ShadoCat If the poster sees the comments before the post is deleted, then yes. Otherwise, it simply vanishes. I'm not sure if users can see their own deleted posts.

Comment: I am pretty sure users can see their own deleted posts...but its been a long time since I couldn't see deleted posts...

Comment: @FrostFyre, That's too bad if it just disappears.  The user may never know what they are doing wrong.

Comment: The user does see it, and it shows a banner with the delete reason (if there is a majority; otherwise it uses the default reason) and who voted in favor.

Comment: Since he was really asking *which delete reason should I use?* this doesn’t actually provide an answer.

Comment: @JDługosz The second point does say which delete reason to use: not an answer.

Comment: This was exactly the reason I chose to vote to delete it when I reviewed it - I could perhaps have added an extra comment, but as L.Dutch already used the canned comment option, I just up-voted that instead.